# Possible to send data between two iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, icloud, nsnotificationcenter

I've read tons of questions about this all over the web, and can't seem to find a solid answer. If I have an iPhone that's running on cellular data and another iOS device on wifi (in two separate locations), is it possible for them to send data to each other directly without sending it first to a web server, then retrieving it? Are the only options sending and receiving from a server/Apple's iCloud? What if I knew the devices' ip addresses? Note that the iPhone has WiFi disabled.

I'm not looking to put this in the app store, it is for personal use. I know `NSNotificationCenter` isn't an option.

Comment: Just use Apple's iCloud, phones while connected to a 3G/4G connection do not get their ip address in the typical fashion.  Any solution would involve a hack, would not be seamless, and would have horrible performance.

Comment: There are only a few ways to send data directly from one device to another - 3G and wifi are the normal methods. You would need both devices to be using the same data service - knowing an IP address doesn't matter if you can't access the wifi network. ECEsurfer's method is probably the best, depending on the exact use you need.

Comment: Hmm. So if they aren't connected to the same network, it wouldn't be possible (since bluetooth seems to be the only option aside from iCloud/Web servers)?

Comment: If both devices are the same iCloud user, that's probably by far the easiest solution to set up. Your other option would be to create some addressable proxy (it doesn't have to be a web server, just addressable from all the networks) that handled the connections and data marshaling. This is actually sort of what GameKit does, so you could actually use that as well (just for the data connection aspects).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the gamekit framework you can send data between two iOS devices. It is easy to implement. Other than that I don't think there is any other way to send data between two iOS devices.

Comment: Yup I just discovered this and was about to add it as my answer, but you beat me to it! ; )

Comment: let me know you need more help in gamekit..:)

Comment: It seems like its impossible to send data from one device to another when they aren't on the same network/within a certain range using GameKit. Is that true? What about sending data between devices in two completely different locations?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it IS possible. You may want to google for something called "UDP hole punching" or "TCP hole punching".

The main approach in short: Assuming you got something like a relay server, that is some server in the internet that is publicly addressable from every private LAN that is connected to the www. No you have your two clients A and B in (different) private LANs, with some Network address translation (NAT) going on, that want to establish a peer to peer connection.

First of all both will tell the server their IP address and the port they have in their own LAN. In the UDP or TCP packet, the server will find the public address and port of the device (or the NAT (router)). So the server knows the private and the public IP address as well as the ports.

If now A wants to communicate with B, it asks the server for help. The server will send a message to B that A wants to communicate with her telling her A's public and private IP and port. A gets back B's public and private information and port.

Now here is where the magic happens. Both clients now send packets out to establish a connection simultaneously to the private and public addresses of the other party and thus punching a whole in their NATs such that incoming connections will not be blocked. Even if one party's connection establishing packets will arrive before this whole is created, the other's packets will get through to such that a connection can be created.

Beware of some NATs that scan the data for IP addresses and translate them as well, but if you encrypt your data or change the appearance of the address (complement, ...) you will be fine.

Now the master question, how can the server communicate with one of the clients without an active connection. Well in this case you can use "connection reversal" and apple's "push notifications". Use the "push notifications" (pn) to tell a client behind a NAT that there is something of interest going on and that it should contact the server. Once it has done that the connection is active and can be used in the previous described fashion.

I hope this helps some people that get to this problem although the post is quite old!

Answer (score 1):

You can only use direct IP address communications if the IP address are publicly reachable IP addresses accessible over the internet, and they are static (enough) so that they are not changing on you regularly as devices get assigned to addresses dynamically. In many (most) cases, that won't be true because your devices will be assigned their IP address dynamically and those addresses are frequently going to be self-assigned IP addresses that aren't publicly addressable.

As others have commented, using Apple-provided mechanisms like iCloud are probably the easiest options. If that's not something you'd like to entertain, there are probably ways to make use of a dynamic DNS service like DynDNS to manage the actual IP addresses of your devices. With something like that you might be able to use a direct IP connection between devices based on a named DNS lookup. You'd probably have to jump through some hoops to make that happen though and I'm not sure you'd want to go to that extent.

Comment: Hmm. Ok, well I'm going to go with Apple provided GameKit. It's well documented, and looks very easy to implement. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

I think that  [Bluetooth](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html) would be a good option for you

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that when the asker tells us the two devices are on different networks, they're out of Bluetooth range.

Comment: Yes @Jacob Oscarson is right. I wouldn't be able to use Bluetooth.

Comment: @JacobOscarson If the OP says so, so it must be; but in case of future downvotes (like I just received). Just because two phones are using 2 different carriers does NOT mean they are out of Bluetooth range. And FYI GameKit (which was the correct answer) also uses Bluetooth.